# How to get actual latency when downloading with curl?

Tags: http, connection, curl

I have an http software that let people be logged and download data according to sent bytes. It's an infinite download until connection stopped. I want to know the time for each download.

The connection is like that:

- Curl start login with header/user etc
- HTTP server answer and start connection
- curl send bytes -> the server answer each times

Before, I were using only `curl -so /dev/null -w '%{time_total}\n' http://my-ip.com:port/something -u login:passwd` to know the total time, but it's only for the connection, not really the actual latency as real users could have, so it's not what I want.

I tried something like that:

```
curl http://my-ip.com:port/something -u login:passwd --header "Connection: Keep-Alive;User-Agent: curl;<omitted output>" --output "<output file>"
```

Where

- `omitted output` correspond to internal values
- `output file` correspond to the answered data by the server

But the `-w 'thing'` filter no longer works, as the request never finished. How can I make it works to get the latency each time I get answer?